# RTL is not working properly using Custom SOTabBar ( Library )

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, tabbar

[image: ScreenShot Custom SOTabBar]

I am currently working on an iOS app that needs to support languages English and Arabic, i am using this libaray to switch from a language to the other. Everything working fine, But just got one isssue with the Selected tabbar. It gets messed up and instead of showing the selected one on the same position, its not!

Comment: Your options are: ask the author of that `SOTabBar` library to support RTL (the issues at that repo show a request made back on Jun 4, 2020), or... edit the library source code yourself to implement RTL support.

Comment: Thank you @DonMag, already edited the source code library, But Still Stuck with one issue of the reloading or updating the tabbar once it localized.